# Match partial text in a div and if it matches text in another div then show a span - jquery and javascript

Tags: jquery, text, match, partial

I need to show the quantity in stock of a product if there is an out of stock message for it:

```
<div class="OutOfStockMessage">Sorry, Avocado is not available in the quantity that you selected. Please select a lower quantity to be able to place this order.</div>
<div class="ItemDecription">Avocado<span class="Quantity" style="display:none"> 16 pieces in stock</span></div>
<div class="ItemDecription">Tomato<span class="Quantity" style="display:none"> 97 pieces in stock</span></div>
<div class="ItemDecription">Mushroom<span class="Quantity" style="display:none"> 217 pieces in stock</span></div>
```

I tried this jQuery however it only works with an exact text match and not with a partial text match:

```
if ( $(".OutOfStockMessage").text() == $(".ItemDecription").text() ) {
$(".Quantity").show();
}
```

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8jmpnwuy/

When .OutOfStockMessage contains the word 'Avocado' plus other words then I need the span inside of the div which contains the word 'Avocado' to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` function to find all itemdescription divs with partial text matching OutOfStockMessage message text.

You can then find the immediate span elements in these sets and show them. I would suggest using a class selector instead of immediate child selector. This makes it less error prone to DOM changes

```
var stockMessageTxt= $(".OutOfStockMessage").text();
var $itemDescrptnToShow = $(".ItemDecription").filter(function(){
  return stockMessageTxt.includes($(this).clone()
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
   .text());
});
$('.Quantity', $itemDescrptnToShow).show();
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/92srcwmL/)**

Comment: Thank you. Words cannot begin to describe how grateful I am for your help. Your answer and code will be put to use on my eCommerce site and help hundreds of people a day.

Comment: @AlexTheDude : Glad it helps :)

Comment: OK I made a mistake and thought that my ecommerce platform had the .Quantity span inside of the .ItemDescription div, however the span is actually after the div and not inside of it. This throws off the working code and I tried for several hours to get it to work without any luck. I will add a link to a fiddle showing how it actually is.

Comment: @AlexTheDude: Hi Alex, As the DOM/HTML is changed, Can you post it as a new question? with properly indented HTML? WIll post the answer.

Comment: Yes, I will post it as a new question with properly indented HTML. I will start working on the new question and should have it posted in just a few minutes. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the question link?

Comment: Yes here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61746654/match-partial-text-in-one-tag-and-if-it-matches-text-in-another-tag-then-show